# want to call async task from handler in eclipse

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-handler

I want to load data from API for the app on the splash screen for some activity.
So I removed async task from that activity and wrote in splash screen.
I want to have splash screen should load for the same time which is provided in handler.i.e `SPLASH_TIME_OUT` and while navigating the data should be loaded on landing activity.
If any mistake in asking question then please correct me.
Basically want to load data on splash screen without getting more time.
Here is the code snippet.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
              // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
            if(CommonUtils.getSavedPreferences(getApplicationContext(), Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN).length()>0)
            {
                  Intent i=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,DashBoardActivity.class);
                  SplashAsync async=new SplashAsync();
                  async.execute("");
                  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  startActivity(i);
            }else{
                  Intent i=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  startActivity(i);
            }



            //Remove activity
           // finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT); //it is set to 3000
```

Async task

```
 public class SplashAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private Dialog mDialog;

    private String response = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            mDialog = new Dialog(SplashActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);          
            mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading);
            mDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        response = callForDirectoryRequest();
        System.out.println(response);

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try{
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.dismiss();

        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();






     mMemberResponseParser = gson.fromJson(response,

                new TypeToken<List<MemberResponseParser>>(){}.getType());    

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String callForDirectoryRequest() {


        String url = Constants.DIRECTORY_URL+"member_email="+CommonUtils.getSavedPreferences(getApplicationContext(), Constants.MEMBER_EMAIL)+"&member_token="+CommonUtils.getSavedPreferences(getApplicationContext(), Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN);

        Log.e("", "URL IS NOW " + url);

        try {


            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity("");

            ServiceCall mServiceCall=new ServiceCall(getApplicationContext(), url, stringEntity);



            response = mServiceCall.getHttpGetServiceResponse();
            System.out.println("################### Response:"+ response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;


    }

}
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: `from handler in eclipse` ???? From handler in an activity or service you mean? Please edit. Further you are not asking anything and your code will not compile. Your story is very unclear.

Comment: Yes in handler as mentioned in the code.

Comment: consider there is menu screen and there are some categories which are displayed as buttons on menu screen and there is a API call when each button is clicked.But for one ot two screen the data is very huge so I decided to load that data on menu screen or on splash screen so that when we click on that category only data needs to displayed as it already loaded on menu or splash screen.